# Plagiarism, ethics, software use,

Tags: ethics, plagiarism, copyright

I want to prepare video courses in the field of informatics sector such as programming, system administration, network administration, cyber security, etc.. and make profit them on Udemy, YouTube, etc.

However, to prepare good quality courses I'll examine technology giant's sites, articles on google scholar, SE sites, blogs, official websites, videos, even courses, books and combine all of them. Of course, I'll change sentence structures and words in my talking and tell in a different way as much as I can.

However, I can't determine if this is plagiarism or not ethical, or if it is needed to give credit how I'll do this.

Even, I don't know if I show the software UI on my courses is copyright or any other right issues.

Can you please give me any advice?

Comment: This question seems to be about copyright law as applied to a for-profit business, so it is off topic.

Comment: Another part of the question would be: in a video where do you put your references?

Answer (score 2):

Plagiarism isn't just about copying words, it's about failing to credit sources, especially those contributing intellectually to some work.

> Of course, I'll change sentence structures and words in my talking and tell in a different way as much as I can

You can't take something you've read and just reorganize the sentence structures and call it your own work. Even just copying paragraph structures and organization is plagiarism. You can, however, read something, then after understanding it, write about it in your own words, and *credit* the source as the place where your understanding originated.

As long as you write in your own words (different from changing sentence structure or using a thesaurus) and cite sources, you are not committing plagiarism. You can cite any source you can access, there's no limit on that (besides exceptions where something is provided to you in private under some sort of non-disclosure agreement, private information protected by law like health information, or censored by a government for national security reasons, etc).

Copyright is a legal issue, and especially if you are planning to profit off some venture you need legal advice beyond what you can get asking questions on StackExchange. You will run into copyright issues if you copy bulk text (even if you cite it and make the original source clear, if you copy "too much" a citation isn't sufficient; where this line is depends on jurisdiction and ultimately what is decided in a courtroom) or reuse images in a way inconsistent with the license those images are provided under.

Answer (score 1):

Textbook writers regularly synthesize information in the way you suggest. Some information is common knowledge. When they take ideas from particular sources they credit those sources, whether they quote directly or paraphrase. Not doing that would violate copyright in many instances.

Without more detail it's hard to advise you. I suggest you look at several books in the areas you want to cover in your videos and see what they do. Look at videos too - you will want to do that in any case since they will compete with yours.